# Marginal Density Function from Variance

Tags: probability

I have an assignment for a lesson:

In general, if
E(X<sup>2</sup>)=[E(X)]<sup>2</sup>=µ<sup>2</sup>, determine
f<sub>X</sub>(x)

I think he made a mistake. E(X<sup>2</sup>)=[E(X)]<sup>2</sup> should be E(X<sup>2</sup>)-[E(X)]<sup>2</sup>. Am I right and how can I determine f<sub>X</sub>(x)

Comment: This random variable doesn't have a density. Did you mean to say $F_X(x)$, i.e. the cumulative distribution function?

Comment: Are you sure because Graham gave some directions?

Comment: The distribution function isn't continuous. So it doesn't have a density in the traditional sense. You'd have to use the Dirac delta, as @Graham Kemp detailed. But it is much simpler to just consider the distribution function, which is 0 for $x<\mu$ and 1 for $x\geqslant\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rephrase the question.

$X$ is a random variable, and $\mu$ is a constant, such that $\mathsf E(X^2) = \mathsf E(X)^2$ and $\mathsf E(X)^2=\mu^2$.  Determine $f_X(x)$ the probability density function of $X$?

**Hint:** What does $\mathsf E(X^2) = \mathsf E(X)^2$ mean about the r.v.?

Comment: Does that mean X is independent.

Comment: @YeşimDokuz : No; Independence requires something to be independent of.  $\\\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2 = 0$ means the r.v. has zero variance, which means what?

Comment: Variance is spread of values, so zero variance means that all values are identical. But from this, where to go? Does this mean that density function is 1?

Comment: @YeşimDokuz So you have a [degenerate distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should I see pdf as 1 for µ and zero for other conditions? Because as you stated, degenerate distribution takes me there.

Comment: Mostly, @YeşimDokuz . The probability *density* is indefinite at $\mu$ and $0$ elsewhere, but integrates to $1$.  Hence the use of the Dirac Delta function. $f_X(x) = \delta (x-\mu)$

Comment: These informations are very valuable for me, I learned a lot from this problem. Thank you very much.